# How to use AND condtion in mongokit when a key has multiple values

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongokit

I have a key in my document named "tag". Now this has the structure like this:

```
"tag": [
    {
      "schemeName": "http:\/\/somesite.com\/categoryscheme2",
      "name": "Test Tag2",
      "value": 1,
      "slug": "test_tag2"
    },
    {
      "schemaName": "http:\/\/somesite.com\/categoryscheme3",
      "name": "Test Tag3",
      "value": 1,
      "slug": "test_tag3"
    }
  ],
```

the values of tag can be passed ',' separated.
How can i use those  values in a AND condition saying return the enrty having tag = test_tag3&test_tag2

Itried it like this : `conditions['tag.slug'] = { '$and': tags }`
where `tags` is array of tags but i got :

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure

OperationFailure: database error: invalid operator: $and
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$in` instead of `$and`:

```
conditions['tag.slug'] = { '$in': tags }
```